# Text Styling and Format in CSV from Visualforce Page

Tags: csv, styles, format, salesforce, visualforce

I am working on Visualforce page. I have a list on visualforce page and I want to export that list in CSV file with some style like BOLD letter and with hyperlink.

I have tried this:

```
<apex:page controller="RequestListController" sideBar="false" showheader="false" standardStylesheets="false" cache="true" contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#List.csv">
    <b>"{!selectedRequestStatus}"</b> List,
    <b>"Total Records:"</b> {!totalRecords},
    <b>"Showing records from {!displayingFrom} to {!displayingTo}"</b>,
    "",
    "Action","Type","Institution","Site","Study","Subject ID","Submitted By","Date Submitted"
    <apex:repeat value="{!appReqList}" var="app">
    "<apex:outputLink value="{!app.Approval_URL__c}">Approve / Reject</apex:outputLink>","{!app.Object_Label__c}","{!app.Institution__r.Name}","{!app.Site__r.Name}","{!app.Study__r.Name}","{!app.Subject_Id__c}","{!app.CreatedBy.Name}","<apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy' 'hh:mm a}"> <apex:param value="{!app.CreatedDate}" /> </apex:outputText>"
    </apex:repeat>
    </apex:page>
```

But this is not working. It is showing html tags as it is. 
can anybody help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** add any formatting to a CSV file.

A CSV file is a plain text file (i.e. you can open it with a notepad and read all its contents), thus you cannot add any formatting to it.

There are programs such as Excel that can read them and even "format" them, but that formatting will only last while the file is open, or if you save it in a different format.

Hence, if you want any formatting, you will have to export results in a different file type.

**NOTE:** You can, however, export that content to Excel using Visualforce. For that, you will need to create a file with a **.xls** extension instead.